# applying a class to a div

Tags: css, class, html

I have a css which has some attribute as follows:

```
.ts{
    background-image: url("images/xyz/pb.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding:0,0,0,20px;
    display:none;
}

.ts.visible{
    display: inline;
}
```

Now i want to apply the this style to a div in my html page.How cna i do it.I dont know css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this: `<div class="ts">... </div>`

But I strongly recommend you take a look at css [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/learning.en.html), it's not that hard.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, what they said. Also, if you want to assign more than one class, use a space to separate them, like so: `<div class="ts visible">`.

Edit:

Also, use spaces to separate the "padding" values, like this: `padding: 0 0 0 20px;`, or just use `padding-left: 20px;`.

Answer (score 1):

Just give that `<div>` a class attribute, like this:

```
<div class="ts"></div>
```

If you want it to have both classes, use a space between like this:

```
<div class="ts visible"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd simply do:

```
<div class="ts">Contents of div</div>
```

That said, I very much suspect that's not the answer you're looking for. :-)